# Custom Key Bindings in SWT

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, swt

Is it at all possible to add custom key bindings to buttons in SWT? I can't use & in the text of the button to set a mnenomic because my buttons have no text (only an image). Is there a good way to do this using key listeners or is there something like the input/action map in swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using `Action`s, but those have to be added to the menu or the toolbar to function. But since this is a usuability standard anyway, be have no problem with doing it so.

Inherit from `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`, and use a `MenuManager` to create your `Menu`s. Immediaty satisfaction guaranteed.